# How to assign function to stored object?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to assign functions to object that then will be stored in the localstorage. I tryed the code below, but I get: "Uncaught TypeError: mydog.woof is not a function"

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}


var Dog = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Dog.prototype.woof = function woof() {
  console.log('woof woof, I am ' + this.name);
}

// Instantinate your objects with `new` keyword
var dog = new Dog('Lovely')
dog.woof()

//Store in the localstorage
localStorage.setObject('mydog', dog); 

//Get from the localstorage
var mydog = localStorage.getObject('mydog');
mydog.woof();
```

Comment: localStorage can only store strings [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: @Justinas Yes I know, So how can I assign functions to an object that will be stored in the localstorage ?

Answer (score 3):

> I need a way to assign functions to object that then will be stored in the localstorage.

Web storage **only** stores strings.

Your best bet is to solve the problem another way, perhaps store a key that you use to look up the function in an object in your script code.

Or, given your `Dog` example, usually what I do in those cases is have a function associated with `Dog` (or even the `Dog` constructor) that accepts a plain object version of a dog and creates a `Dog` version initialized with that data. E.g., roughly:

```
Dog.fromPlainObject = function(plain) {
    var d = new Dog();
    Object.keys(plain).forEach(function(key) {
        d[key] = plain[key];
    });
    return d;
};
```

...or any of a dozen variations on that theme.

You *could* store the string version of the function then reconstitute it via `eval`, but I **really wouldn't**. Use storage for data, not code.